# Send a multidimensional array to stored procedure cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

```
Code Oracle:

 Procedure example
    (
    p_Cod_Rspta             out varchar2             ,
    p_error_Rspta           out varchar2             ,
    p_ID_USUAR              in   Number              ,
    p_reg_Aplic             in   SYS_REFCURSOR       ,
    p_reg_Rta_Excel         out  SYS_REFCURSOR        
    )
```

Here is where I want to send the ref cursor calling the procedure example

```
Code Python:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cursor= cur.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)
    cur.callproc("package.example",[cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING),cur.var(cx_Oracle.STRING),ID_U,cursor,cur.var(cx_Oracle.CURSOR)]
```

Comment: You should consider taking a second look at your post and edit it so as to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion  I edit my question

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What do you mean by "multidimensional array"? I see that you are passing in a cursor but you haven't initialised it in any way!? Maybe I am missing something!

Comment: @anthony I'd like to pass  a multidimesional array something like [['example','example'],['example','example']] into  p_reg_Aplic   that is a ref cursor var

Comment: If you are using 12.1 or higher you can use an array of record. As far as I am aware you can't pass an array of data like you suggest to a ref cursor!

Comment: @anthony  Thanks for you response, Can you tell me How Can I implement  it ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a set of data in as a cursor. The data in a cursor must be populated from a query that is executed in the database. You can, however, pass in an array of records into PL/SQL. Note that this is only possible in Oracle 12c with cx_Oracle 5.3.

Comment: Thanks for you help

Comment: You're welcome. If it answered your question, please accept the answer!